Screen Record with Audio using Pupeteer in Docker container without access to sound card
I am trying to run a app which screen records a meeting with audio, it works perfectly with my system which has a sound card and even can record multiple meetings. The issue is that when I host this on a server without a sound card , the screen record does not have any sound in it.
I have tried setting up pulse audio and sinks but while using pactl command i am always getting connection refused , I have checked lot of resources but nothing is working. Below is the docker file which i am using to accomplish this with rest of the code.
FROM ultrafunk/undetected-chromedriver

RUN mkdir /app /app/recordings /app/screenshots


# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python3 \
    python3-pip \
    pulseaudio \
    pavucontrol \
    curl \
    sudo \
    pulseaudio \
    xvfb \
    libnss3-tools \
    ffmpeg \
    xdotool \
    unzip \
    x11vnc \
    libfontconfig \
    libfreetype6 \
    xfonts-cyrillic \
    xfonts-scalable \
    fonts-liberation \
    fonts-ipafont-gothic \
    fonts-wqy-zenhei \
    xterm \
    vim

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_22.x | bash - && \
apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install PM2 globally
RUN npm install -g pm2

RUN usermod -aG audio root
RUN adduser root pulse-access

ENV key=value DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
ENV XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0


RUN mkdir -p /run/dbus
RUN chmod 755 /run/dbus

RUN rm -rf /var/run/pulse /var/lib/pulse /root/.config/pulse


RUN dbus-daemon --system --fork



RUN wget http://files.portaudio.com/archives/pa_stable_v190700_20210406.tgz

RUN tar -xvf pa_stable_v190700_20210406.tgz

RUN mv portaudio /usr/src/

WORKDIR /usr/src/portaudio

RUN ./configure && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    ldconfig


RUN echo 'user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers

RUN adduser root pulse-access

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/dbus

RUN dbus-uuidgen > /var/lib/dbus/machine-id

#RUN dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address

WORKDIR /app

#COPY chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver

# Copy your application code to the container
COPY . /app

# Set any environment variables if required
ENV X_SERVER_NUM=1
ENV SCREEN_WIDTH=1280
ENV SCREEN_HEIGHT=1024
ENV SCREEN_RESOLUTION=1280x1024
ENV COLOR_DEPTH=24
ENV DISPLAY=:${X_SERVER_NUM}.0

RUN touch /root/.Xauthority
RUN chmod 600 /root/.Xauthority

RUN rm /run/dbus/pid
RUN mv pulseaudio.conf /etc/dbus-1/system.d/pulseaudio.conf

RUN npm install

# Start the application with Node.js
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "src/script.js"]

Before Launching browser I am creating sinks so audio can be routed.Code below
const commands = [
    "sudo rm -rf /var/run/pulse /var/lib/pulse /root/.config/pulse",
    "sudo pulseaudio -D --verbose --exit-idle-time=-1 --system --disallow-exit >> /dev/null 2>&1",
    'sudo pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=DummyOutput sink_properties=device.description="Virtual_Dummy_Output"',
    'sudo pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MicOutput sink_properties=device.description="Virtual_Microphone_Output"',
    "sudo pactl set-default-source MicOutput.monitor",
    "sudo pactl set-default-sink MicOutput",
    "sudo pactl load-module module-virtual-source source_name=VirtualMic"
];

commands.forEach(command => {
    exec(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(`Error executing command "${command}":`, error);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
});
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: [
      '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream',
      '--allow-file-access-from-files',
      '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
      '--disable-gpu','--disable-extensions',
      '--disable-application-cache','--disable-dev-shm-usage'
    ],
    executablePath: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
  });

Tried different pulse audio configurations and running commands in dockerfile also to setup sinks but not working. Everytime getting an error
